# check if variable is set and grep

Tags: bash, grep

i have three variables $a, $b, $c. I don't know whether the three variables are set. I want the variable in the GREP query only if the variables are set. How do i do this?

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -type f | xargs grep -inw "$a" -sl | xargs grep -inw "$b" -sl |  xargs grep -inw "$c" -sl
find .* -iname "*.txt" -type f | xargs grep -iw "$a|$b|$c" -sl
```

Comment: Please edit your question to describe your overall goal. Perhaps you're going about it all wrong.

Comment: Your current edit makes even less sense than the original.

Comment: the second line is a query that i need to use in my script somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare multiple `-e` arguments on an array:

```
args=()
for x in "$a" "$b" "$c"; do
    [[ -n $x ]] && args+=(-e "$x")
done
[[ ${#args[@]} -gt 0 ]] && find . -iname "*.txt" -type f | xargs grep -iw "${args[@]}" -sl
```

Note: Having `-e "$a" -e "$b" -e "$c"` is *practically* synonymous to `"($a|$b|$c)"` and might be even safer. Also if you don't intend "$a", "$b", and "$c" to be parsed as regex, you can just use `fgrep` or add the option `-F`; that which can't be done with `"($a|$b|$c)"`.

Comment: `-n` makes no sense in conjunction with `-l`.

Comment: Nope. You copied it exactly as he had it, even splitting the options into two groups for no reason.